# InvalidGroupIdException for Kafka spout in Storm

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have defined a basic Storm topology with spout consumer from Kafka (producer is created in Kafka separate module). However, when I run the application I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:407) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.
```

How can I set up group id? I am running Storm locally with 2.1.0 version.

Here is the code for the topology:

```
val cluster = new LocalCluster()

val bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
val brokerHosts = new ZkHosts(bootstrapServers)
val topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder()

val spoutConfig = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, "tweets").build()
topologyBuilder.setSpout("kafka_spout", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig), 1)

val config = new Config()
cluster.submitTopology("kafkaTest", config, topologyBuilder.createTopology())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setProp(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)` with `ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG` to add the consumer group id on the `KafkaSpoutConfig`